# what is c++ std::unordered_map default container?

Tags: c++, containers, std, unordered-map

I'm studying about inside logic of unordered_map.

And found that It uses container. And uses key values to find value.

Is the default container of unordered_map std::vector??

And is other containers, for example std::map is able?

Comment: Where did you find that it "uses" a container?

Comment: The documentation might be helpful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: @molbdnilo I ment inside the class, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unordered_map is implemented via hash table, so there is no such thing here as "default container".
Signature:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

The only "defaulted" types here are key hash function, key comparator and allocator.

If you mean the container for holding the buckets, its normally just raw `BucketType*`

Comment: Is hash table made by arrays? or std::vector??